# How To Add Own Template view Inbox In MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, email, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have created MVC5 project. Now using Mail send Concept. It's working fine. Sending an email is working well. Now I plan to add some design to my email. I have created the following template in App_Start/Template/EmailTEmplate.html

```
<html>
<body style="color:grey; font-size:15px;">
    <font face="Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif">

        <div style="position:absolute; height:100px;
width:600px; background-color:0d1d36; padding:30px;">
            <img src="logo" />
        </div>

        <br />
        <br />

        <div style="background-color: #ece8d4;
width:600px; height:200px; padding:30px; margin-top:30px;">

            <p>Dear {0},<p>

            <p>Thank you</p>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

here My  controller Code mail send To inbox

```
public class ContactUsController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Contact
        public ActionResult ContactUs()
        {
            return View();
        }





   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ContactUs(MailModel objModelMail, HttpPostedFileBase fileUploader)

    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string from = "xxx@gmail.com"; 
            using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from, objModelMail.To))
            {
                mail.Subject = objModelMail.Subject;
                mail.Body = objModelMail.Body;
                if (fileUploader != null)
                {
                    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileUploader.FileName);
                    mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(fileUploader.InputStream, fileName));
                }

                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                NetworkCredential networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(from, "password");
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                smtp.Credentials = networkCredential;
                smtp.Port = 587;
                smtp.Send(mail);
                ViewBag.Message = "Sent";
                return View("ContactUs", objModelMail);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

I want my inbox mail to look good? How do I add my template?

Answer (score 0):

You can assignment Layout  in view page :

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MyLayout.cshtml";
}
```

it's ur problem ?

Comment: I am gettingError @Zebra

Comment: i need to  show my  template in inbox not in view page its page view page

Comment: you can display ur inbox in partialview and define ur layout in partialview page .

Comment: ok thank you Zebra  i will try this. i have one more question can i ask

Comment: Prego,happy to help.

Comment: its possible fetch inbox  message after the mail  fetch and show in my site its possible